# Short story about a teleport gateway on Earth

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The story I'm looking for is in a book I read in the mid/end seventies (1970's for time travellers). I can remember fragments from the story:

- Teleport works through replication
- It has limited range, so teleport gateways are needed to spread across the galaxy
- Aliens teleport in and (not sure here) straight back out again leaving behind their inanimate body
- Our protagonist runs one of these gateways on Earth
- It's in a wooden house in or on the edge of a forest
- His job is to clean out the tanks the aliens teleport into by dissolving their left-over bodies after they leave again
- No-one else knows about this setup, he's the only person on Earth who knows about the aliens and the teleport gateways
- One day, one of the aliens escapes before being teleported on
- I think something like a police squad teleports in to try and locate the alien and take it away again

Comment: Hi Winchell, I think you might be right. Which means it wasn't a short story after all. Thanks for linking the two questions. Now to get the book... ;-)

Comment: Agreed, *Way Station*

Comment: Definitely Way Station, one of my favorite SF books in the Sixties.

Comment: @HenryRusted is Way Station the correct book? If it is please let us know so we can mark this as a duplicate of the earlier question. Thanks :-)

Comment: Hi @JohnRennie. Way Station just arrived in the post and, yes, it's the book I have been looking for! Please mark as duplicate and thanks to everyone for the help!